# jQuery.data - how much data can I store in it

Tags: jquery

Is there a limit on how much data I can store using jQuery.data( element, key, value ) ?
Also, where is the data stored ? In memory ?

Thanks

Comment: this article is interesting but does not talk about limits http://apheliondynamics.com/blog/2010/01/19/the-power-of-jquery-data-and-a-practical-example/

Comment: In memory, yes. If you want the data to persist, you could look into HTML5's localStorage  but of course older browsers will need some sort of polyfill to take advantage. I do not know the limit for $.data()

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The data is stored internally in the $.cache object. As per the limit, i did a small experiment with arbitrarily large number of text lines, i can't seem to get it to break, or even throw an exception.