# Data limit of $.data?

Tags: jquery, html, web, client-side, data-storage

I am searching for the solution to store the large amount of data in the client side. But i couldn't figured out the proper way due to some [limitations of some techniques](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15876098/how-to-store-data-locally).

I came to know about [`$.data`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/) but i didn't get any proper information about the [data limits of `$.data`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7734224/jquery-data-how-much-data-can-i-store-in-it).

Any information will be greatful

Comment: see here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7734224/jquery-data-how-much-data-can-i-store-in-it

Comment: What do you mean by "proper information"? The answer you link to says basically "no limit" (i.e. It's likely to be limited only by the client computer's memory).

Comment: Also note that `$.data()` is temporary and not comparable to localstorage or cookies.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It can store up to whatever the operating system allows, which is practically limitless. This is because `$.data` stores the data in object properties and ECMAScript doesn't set any particular memory limit on them.