# How to manage events for a series of group of radio buttons?

Tags: jquery

I have this form on a website and need some help figuring out how to make the jquery code do what I want it to do.

The form looks like this:

```
<div>
 <h4>Pick an option</h4>
 <input type="radio" name="class" value="tree" checked/>Biological <br />
 <input type="radio" name="class" value="radial tree"/>Geological<br />
 <input type="radio" name="class" value="dendogram" />Chemical<br />
</div>
```

What I want to do is display in another div information regarding each option. I'd like this behavior over a hover jquery event. The info text is different for every option of course. I don't want to trigger that event on page load since I already have a default value selected.

What I have going so far is this:

```
var Sel = $("input[name=class]:radio").get();

$.each( Sel, function(index, object) {
    $(this).hover(function() {
        $( "#infodiv" ).slideDown( "slow", function() {
            $("infodiv").addClass('infodivstyle').text('Details here');
        });
    });
});
```

What this does so far is just display that text over hovering one of the radios.

Further I'd like to display a custom text according to the value attribute on the respective html radio element. I also want the infodiv to be hidden once the mouse is somewhere else on the page from the div with the radios.

Anyone have an idea on how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are missing a `<div>` from your question:

```
<div>
 <h4>Pick an option</h4>
 <input type="radio" name="class" value="tree" checked="checked" data-description="bio"/>Biological <br />
 <input type="radio" name="class" value="radial tree" data-description="geo"/>Geological<br />
 <input type="radio" name="class" value="dendogram" data-description="chem"/>Chemical<br />
</div>

<div id="infodiv" >
    some initial description
</div>
```

With that in place and by using the data- functionality of jQuery you can add a mouseover event listener like this:

```
$(document).on('mouseover',"input[name='class']",function(){
    var desc = $(this).data('description');
    $('#infodiv').text(desc);
});
```

Here is a working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/smurphy/Tgj6A/)

Comment: the description is quite a large chunk of text, can't I just use some conditionals in the jquery and test against something to display the correct text?

Comment: Where is the large chunk of text stored? The data- attributes can store a large amount of text. http://stackoverflow.com/a/7734328/1217018

Comment: On second thought, it's not such a big deal, I can embed it into the html just fine.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what all of your requirements are, but this will display the text per type.

```
<style>
.details {
    display: none;
}
</style>

<div>
    <h4>Pick an option</h4>
    <input type="radio" name="class" value="tree" checked="checked" class="option" />Biological <br />
    <input type="radio" name="class" value="radial tree" class="option" />Geological<br />
    <input type="radio" name="class" value="dendogram" class="option" />Chemical<br />
</div>
<div id="details-tree" class="details">Bio Stuff</div>
<div id="details-radial_tree" class="details">Geo Stuff</div>
<div id="details-dendogram" class="details">Chem Stuff</div>

<script>
$(function() {
    $('.option').on('mouseover', function(e) {
        console.log(e);
        $('.details').slideUp('fast');
        var $input = $(e.currentTarget);
        var val = $input.val().replace(' ', '_');
        $('#details-' + val).slideDown('slow');
    });
});
</script>
```